# monitor linux file systems using df

Tags: linux, bash, nfs, disk-usage

I use `df -kh` to get the file system usage, but the trouble is if there is any NFS mount failure in any of the boxes the command will hang.

Is there a better way to monitor file systems other than `df` , or is it possible to mention a timeout to `df` command ?

Comment: Aren't `-k` and `-h` contradictory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay)

The trick is to use the command **timeout**

So the ideal way is `timeout 2 df -kh`  , here 2 is the timeout in seconds.

Comment: I believe that for some older kernels unless the filesystem is mounted with the "intr" flag, then all NFS operations are uninterruptible. I'm not sure what "timeout" does in this case, but I suspect that it abandons the "df" command so you may end up with a bunch of zombie df's in the background.

Comment: I set the timeout to get the output of `df` in 2 seconds. If it is taking more than 2secs there is a trouble in some of the file systems.

Comment: I see in general it returns the results in milli seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df -khl
```

instead. Option `-l` tells `df` to report on local file systems only (from `man df`):

```
-l, --local
    limit listing to local file systems
```

(the `man df` command prints the complete manual page for `df`.)

Comment: I wanted to monitor NFS mounts as well. The trouble is, if there is an issue with the NFS mount the `df` command will go in a hung state.

Comment: 1) nfs drive sould be monitored by their server. 2) however there is no switch to `df` that could timeout, or predict a possible hang. 3) depending on your context, you might wish to use automount or soft NFSmount.